# The prime elements of the ring $ \mathbb{Z} \! \left[ \dfrac{i \sqrt{3} - 1}{2} \right] $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have to study the prime elements of the ring $ \mathbb{Z} \! \left[ \dfrac{i \sqrt{3} - 1}{2} \right] $. For the moment, I cannot find the general form of such elements. Can you help me?

Thanks! :)

Comment: What is $j^2$ ?

Comment: For information and references, please see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_prime) on Eisenstein primes.

Comment: A little hint.... There are two types of primes in $Z$:
4k+1 and 4k+3
Check and see in which structure your j can come in handy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two collections of primes in this ring:

$$
p, pj, \mbox{ and } pj^2 
$$
where $p \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ is a prime of the form $3k+2$, and
$$
a + bj
$$
where $a, b \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ and $a^2 -ab + b^2$ is a prime of the form $3k+2$.

All such numbers are prime and those are the only primes. I think Euler showed this first.

Comment: +1, but I wanted to add that 1) $i\sqrt3$ is also a prime, 2) $-1$ is also a unit giving more associates.

Comment: Don't you mean $a^2-ab+b^2$ of the form $3k+1$ or equal to 3?

Comment: For user10676: You are right, I should have said $a^2 - ab + b^2$ must be a prime *not* of the form $3k + 2$.  Doh!

Comment: o Jyrki -- you are half right. I should have said $\pm p, \pm pj, \pm pj^2$.  But $i\sqrt{3}$, while prime, falls into the second class, with $a = 1, b=2$ and $a^2 -ab + b^2 = 3$ which is prime.  Again, my mis-wording about the prime bing $3k+2$ may have led to this confusin.

Answer (score 1):

These are the Eisenstein primes, and it is more common to use the notation $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ where $$\omega = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2} = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}.$$ (This is a very special number for reasons that may seem like a sidetrack from your question).

According to MathWorld, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EisensteinPrime.html there are three classes of Eisenstein primes:

- $1 - \omega$ all by itself, apparently
- A positive prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ which also satisfies $p \equiv 2 \mod 3$ is also prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. (If instead $p \equiv 1 \mod 3$, it can be divided by Eisenstein integers of smaller norms; for example, try factoring $7$ or $13$).
- A number of the form $a + b \omega$ or $a + b \omega^2$ such that $a^2 - ab + b^2 = p \equiv 1 \mod 3$ is a positive prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$; therefore that prime number is actually composite in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ and one of its factors is $a + b \omega$ or $a + b \omega^2$ (which is what I was getting at with my previous parenthetical).

If you have Mathematica, I would strongly recommend going to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EisensteinInteger.html and downloading that Mathematica notebook to play around with these numbers a little bit. If you don't have Mathematica, try factoring some small positive integers in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, e.g., 19, 23, 27, 29, 31, etc.